# bootstrap datepicker set default date not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker.I want to show 01-01-1960 as selected date in my calendar when it is loaded first time.

javascript

```
 <script src="~/Content/js/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Content/js/datepicker/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
        defaultViewDate: { year: 1960, month: 01, day: 01 },
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    });

});
```

I am using this theme - http://flatfull.com/themes/scale/form-elements.html.

Comment: You may try this `defaultViewDate: new Date(`1960, 01, 01`)

Comment: So, when you do that what do you get as a result? It's not setting default date at all or something else is wrong?

Comment: not getting any error today's date is selected as default date for now even if I have set to '01-01-1960'

Comment: Could you provide a link for this datepicker? Just want to check the source to see.

Comment: I am sure your reasons of this not working are different than what you're thinking. Could you set up a quick fiddle for us to see? I just tried with `defaultViewDate` and it works for me.

Comment: @rupinder18 Try `$('.datepicker-input').datepicker('setValue', new Date(1960, 01, 01))`

Comment: tried it works but also fills value in textbox but I want textbox blank  just the date shows in calendar only

Answer (score 1):

You can set default date like :

```
 <script src="~/Content/js/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Content/js/datepicker/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
        'setDate', new Date(1960, 01, 01 ),
        'format': 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: not working still today's date is shown as highlighted on calendar open

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
          $('.datepicker-input').datepicker('setDate', new Date(1960,00,01));

          $('.datepicker-input').val('');
    });
</script>
```

It Works for me.

Comment: not working for me getting this error-Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function

Comment: I think, that data[option] error is not from my script. Where you have that error?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    setDate: new Date(1960, 01, 01),
});
```

Set `useCurrent` to `false`, then `setDate` would work.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the following error:

> error-Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function

You should use the option setValue instead of setDate!

```
$(".datepicker-input").datepicker("setValue", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple solution for setting default value on this problem.

According to the research from google, you cannot simple add 'default date' option here but you can set 'setDate' option. Thus, For example...

```
<div class="fullDate input-group date" id="atdcRegReqDtDiv">
<input type="text" class="form-control inputstl" id="REQ_DT">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="dtPick glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Add the setDate option, to the object, and then put empty value to the text input.

```
$('#atdcRegReqDtDiv').datepicker('setDate', "2018-09-14");
$('#REQ_DT').val("");
```

Then, you can see the empty input box with the calendar has default Year/Month.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

> You can set default date using Jquery **defaultDate** :

```
defaultDate: new Date(1960, 01, 01);
```